# Would a question about music notation software be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, software

After a discussion on the chat about computers in music, this question came up.

Would a question about how to use a certain software for making scores or other music notation be on topic? Say if you have a problem with doing something specific in "Sibelius" or whatever?

(I'll give my opinion as an answer, any other opinions are welcome, I'll just select the one that gets the highest votes in a week or so).

Comment: It should be, it's just a tool like any other. There is, however, an overlap for questions that aren't really about the music aspect of that software...

Answer (score 28):

My answer: Yes.

A question about notation software is not about music per se, but about one of the tools. But an amplifier or a guitar pedal is also a tool. And in fact, the guitar itself is just a tool used to make music.

So excluding questions about how to use notational software seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: "usage of specific music software or hardware" -- https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic